# Has anyone experienced one form element activating another on iOS / iPhone?

Tags: ios, iframe

I have a form that appears in a FancyBox iframe modal. On iOS 5 (specifically on an iPhone - does not occur on iPad) when I touch the submit button it activates a `<select>` that appears about 50 pixels above the submit button and I'm then presented with the `<select>` options at the bottom of the screen.

I've zoomed in as much as possible to verify that I'm not touching the select – I am indeed clicking on the submit button and it highlights itself as expected, but the form of course does not submit and I get the options to pick from.

Has anyone experienced a bug like this in iOS 5? I can't pin this down to anything else – there is some javascript that would normally run to process the form on submit click but it's not being activated at all and it has no effect on the form itself, the `<select>`, etc. I have seen several odd things with iframes on iOS and wonder if there is a potential correlation.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the connections for your actions going to different buttons than the outlets. That would explain why the right thing would happen (Action is OK) but updating the Frame Rect would get messed up (Outlet is on the wrong button).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! I was referring to HTML markup in iOS 5 Safari. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

iframes on ios don't behave like normal iframes in every other browser (including desktop safari).

ios safari renders them at the full height of the page inside the iframe.

To get them to scroll like a normal iframe of fixed height you have to put them in a div and set the divs overflow to auto or scroll. I'm guessing your modal overlay is already doing that.

But even a plain in-page iframe with no special positioning (other than using a parent div to crop its height and make it scrollable) will often only have the submit button work 1 time if the submit buttons original rendered location was below the fold of the parent div.

So the first submission will work, but if the form comes back with missing required field errors you can't hit the submit button again.

Further research on my old ipad shows that if the submit button is down far enough it won't even work that first time.

The bug is present in safari for ios 5.1.1 and also **ios 8** !!!

I can use an onclick javascript function on any element in the iframe that is not an input type=submit to force the form to form.submit().

But specifically about the iphone issue what was probably happening was that the OS was trying to zoom in to the form field so the use could clearly see what they were typing. The fix for that might be to declare a font-size of at least 16px on input elements. That way the OS knows the text in the field is already at a fairly readable size and won't try to zoom in. Zooming in to the contents of an iframe within an absolutely positioned modal overlay is super buggy even in ios 8.